# Use Netfilter to programatically set packet destination and route them

Tags: networking, iptables, router, netfilter

I'm new to iptables and its modules and I would like help in rapping my head around it.

---

### The Problem

Managing large scale NAT routing. I need to handle more then 100,000 static IPs (and growing) and route them to one of N environments.

---

### The Goal

The goal is to have a dynamic DNAT routing. What that means can be explained by this flow:

1. A network layer request is received by the machine (linux).
2. Netfilter intercepts the request **programatically**
3. Netfilter change the destination to a **public** IP
4. FORWARD the request

### Current Solution

Currently the implementation is done staticky. By using the following DNAT rule for each IP and a rule with MASQUERADE to handle the SNAT

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s {USER-STATIC-IP_1} -j DNAT --to-destination {ENV-IP_1}
...
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s {USER-STATIC-IP_N} -j DNAT --to-destination {ENV-IP_N}
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Issues:

- Scaling - the iptables rules can't grow forever.
- Replication - The rules data isn't central and is cashed on each machine.
- Management - managing N rules and syncing them between machine is cumbersome.
- Logs - logging is possible but not stream line. We need to use the LOG iptables Module
- No Direct Control - There is no real control over the packet flow. We can only add and remove static rules but can't interact with the packets.

---

### The Challenges

- intercept network request using Netfilter (I wasn't able to find outher module that can programatically intercept request)
- Async handleling of request. I would like to store the IP addresses in a DB (a fast one) to centralise all the IPs.
- Updating **packet** destination without corruption it
- The response need to be routed back to the user (MASQUERADE style).
- The program language that is used to integrate with Netfilter should be fast (can be compiled) and friendly to new programers (I found libs in [python](https://pypi.org/project/NetfilterQueue/) and [go](https://github.com/AkihiroSuda/go-netfilter-queue)).

---

This is quite a mouth fill of a question and this is a real chalange for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem you are trying to solve, not just the solution you found?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I have updated the post